# Optimise query with count and order by function

Tags: sql-server, sorting, t-sql, count, query-optimization

I have a problem with the optimization of this query, I have 3 tables (Products = `Catalogo.GTIN`, Sales Header = `TEDEF.Factura` and Sales Detail = `TEDEF.Farmacia`).

The query tries to find the `Mode` of the column `VPRODEXENIGV_FAR`. This query without the `ORDER BY` executes in less than 3 seconds (the table of details has about 30 million rows).

But when I add the `ORDER BY` clause, the query now takes more than 30 minutes to run.

I want to know how can I optimize this query or the indexes that I need to optimize this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Catalogo.GTIN G
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         COUNT(FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR) [ROW],
         YEAR(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) [AÑO],
         MONTH(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) [MES],
         FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003,
         CASE WHEN FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AfectoIGV
     FROM 
         TEDEF.Factura FAC2
     INNER JOIN 
         TEDEF.Farmacia FAR ON FAC2.VTDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VTDOCPAGO_FAC
                            AND FAC2.VNDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VNDOCPAGO_FAC
     WHERE 
         G.CODIGO = FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003
     GROUP BY 
         YEAR(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC),
         MONTH(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC),
         FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003,
         FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR
     ORDER BY 
         1 DESC --- <----- THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    ) GG
```

Comment: For performance optimisation questions you need to provide the table and index definitions, and the execution plan using "Paste The Plan". Its rarely possible to know anything performance related just from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is me again, Finally i resolve the problem of the optimization, now the query delay is about 20 sec (with the sort instruction and with the count in a table over 30 million rows) i hope this way can help others or could be optimice more by the community.
I resolve the problem applying the sort but with the Row_Number instruction, in that way the server take my index for the sort instruction and make the magic:

```
WITH x
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GG.COD, GG.[AÑO], GG.[MES] ORDER BY GG.[ROW] DESC) [ID]
    FROM Catalogo.GTIN G
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT COUNT(FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR) [ROW]
                , YEAR(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) [AÑO]
                , MONTH(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) [MES]
                , FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003 [COD]
                , CASE WHEN FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AfectoIGV
            FROM TEDEF.Factura FAC2
            INNER JOIN TEDEF.Farmacia FAR
                ON FAC2.VTDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VTDOCPAGO_FAC
                    AND FAC2.VNDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VNDOCPAGO_FAC
            WHERE G.CODIGO = FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003
            GROUP BY YEAR(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC)
                , MONTH(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC)
                , FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003
                , FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR
--            ORDER BY 1 DESC   --- <---- this is the bad guy, please, don't do that xD
        ) GG
) SELECT *
FROM x WHERE ID = 1
```

In that way i can sort the Count instruction and calculate the Mode for the Column **FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR**

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! You have a hugely expensive dependent subquery. It's expensive because `SELECT TOP(n) ... ORDER BY col DESC` does a whole lot of work to create a result set only to discard all but one row.  And, it's a dependent subquery so it's run for every row of `Catalogo.GTIN` .

It looks like you want to count the resultset rows in the most recent month and year for each `Catalogo.GTIN` row. So, let's try to refactor your query to do that.

We'll start with a subquery to grab the month-start date of the latest `Factura` row for each catalog entry.

```sql
                   SELECT CODIGO,
                          DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(maxd), MONTH(maxd),1) maxmes
                     FROM (
                       SELECT MAX(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) maxd,
                              G.CODIGO
                         FROM Catalogo.GTIN G
                         JOIN TDEF.Farmacia FAR
                               ON G.CODIGO = FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003
                         JOIN TEDEF.Factura FAC2
                               ON FAC2.VTDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VTDOCPAGO_FAC
                              AND FAC2.VNDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VNDOCPAGO_FAC
                        GROUP BY G.CODIGO
                       ) maxd
```

It's wise to test this and make sure it works correctly and performs tolerably well.  If you test it in SSMS, you can use "Show Actual Execution Plan" and see if it recommends an extra index. This subquery need only be run once, rather than once per G.CODIGO row.

Then we'll use it in your larger query.

```sql
SELECT G.*,
       COUNT(FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR) [ROW],
       YEAR(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) [AÑO],
       MONTH(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) [MES],
       FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003,
       CASE WHEN FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AfectoIGV
  FROM Catalogo.GTIN G
  JOIN (
                   SELECT CODIGO,
                          DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(maxd), MONTH(maxd),1) maxmes
                     FROM (
                       SELECT MAX(FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC) maxd,
                              G.CODIGO
                         FROM Catalogo.GTIN G
                         JOIN TDEF.Farmacia FAR
                               ON G.CODIGO = FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003
                         JOIN TEDEF.Factura FAC2
                               ON FAC2.VTDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VTDOCPAGO_FAC
                              AND FAC2.VNDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VNDOCPAGO_FAC
                        GROUP BY G.CODIGO
                       ) maxd
       ) maxmes ON G.CODIGO = maxmes.CODIGO
  JOIN TEDEF.Farmacia FAR 
         ON G.CODIGO = FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003
  JOIN TEDEF.Factura FAC2
         ON FAC2.VTDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VTDOCPAGO_FAC
        AND FAC2.VNDOCPAGO_FAC = FAR.VNDOCPAGO_FAC
        AND FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC >= maxmes.maxmes
 GROUP BY maxmes.maxmes, 
          G.CODIGO,
         FAR.VCODPROD_FAR_003,
         FAR.VPRODEXENIGV_FAR
```

Here is the tricky bit:

`DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(maxd), MONTH(maxd),1) maxmes` turns any date `maxd` into the first day of that month.

And, `FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC >= maxmes.maxmes` filters out rows before the first day of that month (for that CODIGO).  It does so in a [sargable](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28838/sargeable) way: a way that can exploit an index on `FAC2.VFECEMI_FAC`.

That is an alternative way to do `TOP(1) ORDER BY d DESC`. And faster.

It's all about sets of rows.  Especially when using GROUP BY, it's performance-helpful to limit the number of rows in each set.

**Obviously I cannot debug this.**